# How to prevent adding class to more than two element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

I have table with selectable cells and now I try to prevent selecting more than two cell at once. It should work like that: If I click cell id `4` then it should get class `selected` if next I click cell id `16` then it also should get class `selected` but if next I click cell id `20` then cell id `4` should have removed class `selected` and id `20` should get class `selected`.
I already have something like that [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dz4Lu6r8/)

```
$(".currency-cell").click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected"))
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    else {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
}).hover(function(){
   $(this).css("background","gold");
},
function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("selected"))
        $(this).css("background","gold");
    else
        $(this).css("background","silver");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store `id` of selected element in array. When td is clicked insert id of it to end of array or if exist in array remove it. If length of array is great than 2 remove first index of array.

```js
var selectedIds = [];
$(".currency-cell").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");

    var id = $(this).attr("id");  
    if (selectedIds.indexOf(id) == -1)
       selectedIds.push(id);
    else   
        selectedIds.splice(selectedIds.indexOf(id), 1);
    
    if (selectedIds.length > 2) {  
        $("#" + selectedIds[0]).removeClass("selected");
        selectedIds.splice(0, 1);
    }       
});
```

```css
table { 
    width: 200px; 
}
.currency-cell {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
.selected { 
    background-color: gold; 
}
.currency-cell:hover { 
    background: gold; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="24" class="currency-cell"></td>
        <td id="6" class="currency-cell"></td>
        <td id="4" class="currency-cell"></td>
        <td id="14" class="currency-cell"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="1" class="currency-cell"></td>
        <td id="7" class="currency-cell"></td>
        <td id="8" class="currency-cell"></td>
        <td id="22" class="currency-cell"></td>            
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="27" class="currency-cell"></td>
        <td id="30" class="currency-cell"></td>
        <td id="28" class="currency-cell"></td>
        <td id="29" class="currency-cell"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can test it on full of your html in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dz4Lu6r8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the selected elements in array and remove the first element when it's `length` is `3`.

```js
var arr = [];
$(".currency-cell").click(function(){
 var ele = $(this);
    arr.push($(this));
    if(arr.length == 3){
      var preEle = arr.shift();
      preEle.removeClass("selected");
    }
  if(ele.hasClass("selected")) {
        ele.removeClass("selected")
      } else {
        ele.addClass("selected");
    }

}).hover(function(){
   $(this).css("background","gold");
},
function(){
  if($(this).hasClass("selected")){
   $(this).css("background","gold");
  } else {
   $(this).css("background","silver");
  }
});
```

```css
.currency-cell {
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 40px 40px;
 border: 1px solid silver;

}
.currency-table {
 width: 560px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: silver;
 -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
   -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
   -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
   user-select: none;          /* Likely future */ 
}
.ratio-table {
 margin: 0 auto;
 -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
   -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
   -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
   user-select: none;          /* Likely future */ 
}
.selected {
 border: 1px solid red;
 background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content" style="background-color:white;">
               <table class="currency-table">
               <tr>
                    <td id="24" class="currency-cell mirror"> </td>
                    <td id="6" class="currency-cell exalted"> </td>
                    <td id="4" class="currency-cell chaos"> </td>
                    <td id="14" class="currency-cell regal"> </td>
                    <td id="5" class="currency-cell gcp"> </td>
                    <td id="2" class="currency-cell fusing"> </td>
                    <td id="3" class="currency-cell alchemy"> </td>
                    <td id="16" class="currency-cell vaal"> </td>
                    <td id="15" class="currency-cell divine"> </td>
                    <td id="13" class="currency-cell regret"> </td>
                    <td id="10" class="currency-cell chisel"> </td>
                    <td id="11" class="currency-cell scouring"> </td>
                    <td id="12" class="currency-cell blessed"> </td>
                    <td id="9" class="currency-cell chance"> </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                    <td id="1" class="currency-cell alteration"> </td>
                    <td id="7" class="currency-cell chromatic"> </td>
                    <td id="8" class="currency-cell jewellers"> </td>
                    <td id="22" class="currency-cell transmut"> </td>
                    <td id="23" class="currency-cell augument"> </td>
                    <td id="21" class="currency-cell glassblower"> </td>
                    <td id="20" class="currency-cell blacksmith"> </td>
                    <td id="19" class="currency-cell scrap"> </td>
                    <td id="17" class="currency-cell wisdom"> </td>
                    <td id="18" class="currency-cell portal"> </td>
                    <td id="26" class="currency-cell coin"> </td>
                    <td id="35" class="currency-cell silver"> </td>
                    <td id="40" class="currency-cell offering"> </td>
                    <td id="25" class="currency-cell eternal"> </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                    <td class=""></td>
                    <td id="27" class="currency-cell dusk"> </td>
                    <td id="30" class="currency-cell noon"> </td>
                    <td id="28" class="currency-cell midnight"> </td>
                    <td id="29" class="currency-cell dawn"> </td>
                    <td id="31" class="currency-cell grief"> </td>
                    <td id="34" class="currency-cell ignorance"> </td>
                    <td id="32" class="currency-cell rage"> </td>
                    <td id="33" class="currency-cell hope"> </td>
                    <td id="39" class="currency-cell volkuurs"> </td>
                    <td id="38" class="currency-cell inyas"> </td>
                    <td id="36" class="currency-cell ebers"> </td>
                    <td id="37" class="currency-cell yriels"> </td>
                    <td class=""></td>
               </tr>
               
               </table>
              
  </div>
```